# Hibernate errro : nested transactions not supported

Tags: java, hibernate

when i use OSIVFilter ; i get the error xD
this is filter code;

```
  Session session= HibernaterUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
    try{
        doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse,filterChain);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }finally {
        HibernaterUtil.closeCurrentSession();
    }
```

this is how use ThreadLocal get CurrentSession in HibernateUtil.class;

```
   public static Session getCurrentSession() {

    Session session = (Session) threadlocal.get();
    if (session == null) {
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        threadlocal.set(session);
    }
    return session;
}
```

but finally just get this error

```
org.hibernate.TransactionException: nested transactions not supported
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.begin(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:154)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1471)
at com.hjy.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:26)
at com.hjy.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:28)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProcessor.process(Http11AprProcessor.java:876)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:612)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$Worker.run(AprEndpoint.java:1777)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

i`m new to hibernate , anyone can tell me how to solve it;

Answer (score 0):

If there is an exception in the "try catch" block there is no `rollback` in catch block for exceptions

you should write it:

```
Session session= HibernaterUtil.getCurrentSession();
Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
try{
    doFilter(servletRequest,servletResponse,filterChain);
    tx.commit();
}catch(Exception e){
    tx.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
    throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
}finally {
    HibernaterUtil.closeCurrentSession();
}
```

---

you should also check if in your  `HibernaterUtil.closeCurrentSession()` method `threadlocal` is cleared.

Comment: sry i forget add it; but after i add it , it`s not work too, and in HibernaterUtil.closeCurrentSession() i have cleared the threadlocal, I think it may the getCurrentSeesion method is error , so I change it to openSeesion , but it print too much connection

Comment: what's on your MyFilter.java file line 26 and 28?

at com.hjy.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:26)
at com.hjy.filter.MyFilter.doFilter(MyFilter.java:28)